# Looking for a fantasy/sci-fi young adult book about kids fighting to get to the top of the tower

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I vaguely remember reading a book about a world where people are divided into different groups (with different abilities/powers) and are selected to go fight. It's kinda got a Hunger Games/Divergent feel to it. The ones who win go to different rooms and have to complete challenges. I'm not real sure about the tower part but they have to come first for something.

Comment: What time period did you read this in? Was it a paperback or a hardback? What country and language?

Comment: [kingdoms of the wall](http://www.amazon.com/Kingdoms-Wall-Robert-Silverberg/dp/0553093096) perhaps?

Comment: Is it Ender's Game?

Answer (score 1):

*The Seventh Tower* by Garth Nix?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you elaborate on why this book matches the question?

Comment: Unless it's one of the later books in the series, I don't think that this is the one that Niyati is looking for. Although the protagonist intends to compete in a (one room) obstacle course, he actually competes in a music competition. And that only takes place over a small portion of the book.

Comment: Yeah. And there aren’t really any “different abilities/powers,” but a few different systems.

Comment: Hello Alison Dee, and welcome to the SF & Fantasy Stack. Perhaps you could include an outline of the plot or perhaps address the specific points the asker remembers, to help them decide if this is indeed what they are looking for. By the way, have you taken the [tour] yet?